# Unread e-mails from Gmail account

Tags: python, gmail

I have a python script as follows:

```
import imaplib, re
import os
import time
import socket

imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
mail.login("user", "pass")
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.

while True:
    try:
        result, data = mail.uid('search', None, 'UNSEEN')
        uid_list = data[0].split()
        print len(uid_list), 'Unseen emails.'
        if len(uid_list) > 20:
         os.system('heroku restart --app xxx')
        time.sleep(60)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Quitting'
        pass
```

The goal is to check how many unread emails there is and restart a Heroku server. The problem is that it doesn't seem to work very well.

```
~# python gmail_new.py
1 Unseen emails.
0 Unseen emails.
```

When I start the first time, it works (1 unread email), but the second time it should have returned 20 and not 0. And next is also 0, never more than 0. I can't seem to figure out why.

Comment: I can't reproduce: with my account I get "1 Unseen emails" printed over and over again.

Comment: Also, why would it return 20 the second time? Did you get 19 new emails in the minute that it was waiting? Also, are you sure you didn't check that email in the intervening minute?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell, you get one extra unseen email all the time.
Make sure you have a few unread mails in your account.
replace :

```
print len(uid_list), 'Unseen emails.'
```

with

```
print len(uid_list)-1, 'Unseen emails.'
```

this should work.